# A regular expression to find a word and also exclude another word/string

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression as follows:

te\b"[^Haste]"

I want to find all words ending with "te" in each segment but need to exclude the word "Haste" and possibly few other words as they are sometimes flooding the list of errors as false positives.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated :-)

I tried to look it up here and there with no success. Also, many tries on regex101 with no success.

Comment: Does this work  https://regex101.com/r/Lakv2a/1 ?

Comment: `[^Haste]` means match one character that is not `H`, `a`, `s`, `t` or `e`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\b(?!(?:Haste|AAAte)\b)\w*te\b
```

`\b` word boundary.

`(?!(?:Haste|AAAte)\b)` that is not followed by the word `Haste` or `AAAte`.

`\w*` zero or more word character.

`te` the string `te`.

`\b` word boundary.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gr5e3d/1)

Comment: If you are using the non capture group in the lookahead, then you might also shorten it to `\b(?!(?:Has|AAA)te\b)\w*te\b` :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is a good catch, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to match, but not capture, what you don't want and capture what you do want. Suppose we wanted to skip over "haste" and "paste". We could then use the following regular expression.

```
\b(?:haste|paste|(\w*te))\b
```

Suppose the string were as follows.

```
"In the surgeon's haste to amputate he removed the wrong leg."
```

The string pointer maintained by the regex engine would move from left to right one character at a time until it matched a word in the sentence ending in `"te"`. The first would be "haste". That would be matched but not captured. We therefore pay no attention to that match.

Next, "amputate" is matched by

```
(\w*te)
```

As it is captured as well we find that "amputate" is a valid match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1PZZMp/1).